# Java carriage return \r doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: java, carriage-return

Here's my java code:

```java
// file name is Strings.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String txt = "Hello\rWorld!";
        System.out.println(txt);

        String txt2 = "Trying\rthis";
        System.out.println(txt2);
    } 
}
```

And I tried to execute it from my terminal, and saw this:

```sh
$ java Strings.java 
World!
thisng
```

I have also tried to execute this from Visual Studio Code, same results. So the outputs are different than what is written in [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/java/tryjava.asp?filename=demo_strings_r). Could someone please tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: What do you think should happen instead? What makes you think so?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Actually you are wrong, since java 10 or so, you can compile and run a single source file with the command java X.java

Comment: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330 It's Java 11, sorry

Comment: `$ java Strings.java` executes code of `Strings.java` but you are showing code of `class Main`.

Comment: Looks like it works exactly as I would expect. Try with \n instead.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/tryjava.asp?filename=demo_strings_r

Comment: @user16320675 Just tested it. Indeed `java Strings.java` ***works*** despite `Strings.java` holding code as `public class Main{...}` (which `javac` wouldn't allow since public top-level classes should be in files with same name as class name, meaning it would expect `Main.java`). Learned something new today. Thank you.

Comment: @Pshemo [JLS 7.6. Top Level Class and Interface Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6-510): *" If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a class or interface is not found in a file under a name composed of the class or interface name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true: .... - The class or interface is declared public ..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the operation system: Linux (`\n`), Mac (`\r`), Windows (`\r\n`). All have different `new line` symbols. See [Adding a Newline Character to a String in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline).

To get an actual combination, do use:

```java
System.lineSeparator()
```

According to your example:

```java
System.out.println("Hello" + System.lineSeparator() + "World!");
System.out.println("Trying" + System.lineSeparator() + "this");
```

Output:

```sh
$ java Strings.java 
Hello
World!
Trying
World!
this
```

This is a bit ugly, but a universal solution.

***P.S.** As alternative, you can use `System.out.format()` instead:*

```java
System.out.format("Hello%nWorld!%n");
System.out.format("Trying%nthis%n");
```

***P.P.S.** I think in general it is better to build a list of lines and use `System.out.println()`:*

```java
Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!").forEach(System.out::println);
Arrays.asList("Trying", "this!").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `format` with `%n` which is replaced by the platform line separator, so could use this:

```
System.out.format("Hello%nWorld!%n");
```